# C# using different endpoints to the same WebService

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a setup, with a dev- test- and production environment. So when development and testing is done, each server has the same WebServices.
This is my first time doing so, but on the dev. environment I’ve written a WebService, and a C# client, using the Visual Studio (2017) ‘Add Service Reference’ feature. So I have an app.config file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BizTalkInterfaceServiceSoapBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/and/so/on"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BizTalkInterfaceServiceSoapBinding"
          contract="ServiceReference.BizTalkInterface" name="BizTalkInterfacePort" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And a Connected Services->ServiceReference structure, with a .wsdl, configuration.svcinfo, configuration91.svcinfo and Reference.svcmap files. I don’t know if there is any point in showing the contents of these files?

I initialize the client like this:

```
protected BizTalkInterfaceClient client;

protected ServiceBase()
{
    client = new BizTalkInterfaceClient("BizTalkInterfacePort");
    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "xxx@xxxdomain";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "xxxxxx";
}
```

Anyhow - This is all well and good, and works fine.

If you haven’t figured it out yet :-), I would like to define two other named endpoints, but I’m unsure on how to do it. Is there a wizard like way to do it, or do I have to copy/past the endpoint in the app.config and configuration files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to copy and paste this endpoint in your `<client>` node:

```
 <endpoint address="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/and/so/on"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BizTalkInterfaceServiceSoapBinding"
      contract="ServiceReference.BizTalkInterface" name="BizTalkInterfacePort" />
```

and just give it a different name.

Also, when you initialize you client you would use the corresponding name here:

```
client = new BizTalkInterfaceClient("BizTalkInterfacePort");
```

example:

```
<endpoint address="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx/and/so/on"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BizTalkInterfaceServiceSoapBinding"
      contract="ServiceReference.BizTalkInterface" name="BizTalkInterfacePortProd" />

client = new BizTalkInterfaceClient("BizTalkInterfacePortProd");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, and sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I actually thought I had tried you solution, but I’ve must have missed something, caused it worked like a charm. Again thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If your service has multiple service endpoint, it should be like

```
 <service name="Service.CalculatorService"  >
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:3721/calculator"  binding="basicHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="ECMSBindingConfig" contract="ServiceInterface.ICalculatorService"></endpoint>
     <endpoint address="http://localhost:4000/calculator"  binding="wsHttpBinding"   contract="ServiceInterface.ICalculatorService"></endpoint>
  </service>
```

And then you could add reference to the service using wsdl address.
After adding reference, there should be two endpoint in your client with endpoint name, like

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:3721/calculator" binding="basicHttpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculatorService" contract="Calculator.ICalculatorService"
  name="BasicHttpBinding_ICalculatorService" />
<endpoint address="http://localhost:4000/calculator" binding="wsHttpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICalculatorService" contract="Calculator.ICalculatorService"
  name="WSHttpBinding_ICalculatorService">
```

Then in your client , you could initialize your client using the name of your configuration just as Popo has written.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write a reply. I don’t have control over the server side og things, but it turns out that it was not necessary, and that @Popo suggestion was sufficient. But thanks a lot anyway